# argparse missing in python 3

Tags: python, command-line, python-3.x, argparse

does somebody know, why the argparse module didn't make it in python 3? it's new in python 2.7, but the 2.x branch is running out with 2.7. it makes no sense to me not to support it in the actual python 3 branch.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It will be in Python 3.2. It was just added in Python 2.7, which was released just this July; Python 3.2 will be the next 3.x release after that date.

Answer (score 4):

argparse *is* in Python 3, 3.2 to be specific. See also: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0389/