# No argparse module shipping with python 3.1.2 on Mint 10

Tags: python-3.x

Why is this happening:

```
$ python3
Python 3.1.2 (release31-maint, Dec  9 2011, 20:50:50) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import argparse
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named argparse
```

I installed python3 precisely because I wanted to use argparse, which was new in 2.7, and the default version on Ubuntu Server 10.04 is 2.6.
Another thing I've noticed: Mint 10 comes with python 2.6.6, which *does* include argparse, and the exact version that ships with ubuntu-server 10.04 is 2.6.5 which does not have argparse. Also, I've noticed that on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine python3 is 3.2.3 and this does come with argparse. Why would this module not be included with 3.1.x???

Comment: possible duplicate of [argparse missing in python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817481/argparse-missing-in-python-3)

Comment: 3.1 was released before 2.7, so to get things that are new in 2.7 you need 2.7 or 3.2.

Answer (score 1):

Although `argparse` only made it into the standard lib on Python 2.7 and Python 3.2, for older/other versions you can still get it from [pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/argparse).

Keep in mind though that this version may not include all the updates that happened since the merge of argparse to the standard lib (as it's explained [on the original project's webpage](http://code.google.com/p/argparse/)).